# Directory path for home to an external NTFS hard drive

Tags: home-directory, authentication, ftp

OK, I have run into a problem with authentication and I think I have figured out the problem but i cant seem to find the solution anywhere I look.  I am using Ubuntu 12.04 running Lamp (individually installed and configured), proftpd, and webmin. I am setting up a [website](http://www.bdsmhouse.net) and one of the things it will offer is ftp based file management and backups. Ive noticed **I can login with any user created on the Linux files system** BUT the **ftp users** that i have **created with their home directories based on the external NTFS** had get a constant error 530. I've played with permissions a lot but I don't wont to let them free of their root bindings. I saw a clue in another post:

> "Instead of messing with mount points, you can create a link to /media/300gb/documents like this:
>
> ```
> ln -s /media/300gb/documents ~/documents"
> ```

(which caught my eye, but the clue was a response to that)

> "mikewhatever
>   8,25311025
>   it is half-solution. It makes link in documents folder and path looks like ~/documents/documents – tilly willy May 9 '12 at 0:49"

I am very new to all this and struggling to do this with as much research on my own as I can. When I checked my log files I saw

```
notice: unable to use '~/' [resolved to '/media/ftp1/ftp/skittishtrigger/']: 
Permission denied
Preparing to chroot to directory '~/'
 chroot to '~/' failed for user 'skittishtrigger':
Operation not permitted
 error: unable to set default root directory

FTP session closed.
```

So I guess the question is how can I define a path to a external `/home` that isn't defined by a leading `~/`? (without having to reformat external drive to ext3/4)

Comment: the user `skitt*` must have execute permissions. If not, he can't cwd to ~/. the directories /home, /home/skitt*, /home/skitt*/bla...etc should have x permissions set.

Comment: As a run through for permissions i chmod the entire basic file structure /media/storage/folder/user and the root of storage /media/storage to 777. not working still even with basically opening up all rights to all users.   Researched giving individual user rwx permisions but saw only answers about making files/dir rwx.

Comment: that's odd. Is Selinux enabled? What's the output of `getenforce`

Comment: Nope, selinux isnt even installed. as a setup solution i have pretty much disabled most security so i can re-enable one by one for trouble shooting purposes. so the getenforce wont out anything atm.

Comment: ok, i backedup everything and changed external file system to ext4, and was able to chmod and chown permisions (with execute) properly.  Still getting the same error though. At a loss here. Learned a bunch in the process though! I am really at a loss, if i need to post any more info to help troubleshit this let me know and i will. I have access to all my files at all times so i will respond as quick as i can. maybe I need to bind location? home directory was created with the gui in user groups applet

Comment: Have a look at the last 2 posts in [this thread](http://www.plugout.net/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=253). Maybe you're suffering from the same problem. I also thought NTFS might be an issue but no such luck. Sorry... I'm useless here. Let's hope one of the gurus comes by and saves you. I am sure you checked your proftpd.conf file a hundred times already but editing your question and posting it can't hurt.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, i did a quick run through and nothing popped out but the make share dir/ looks promising. Ill post after work the mount and results of that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok, my problem here was an invalid entry in the /home folders location duplicating the home directory. I removed the user (keeping the external home directory intact) delected the original home directory and recreated the user. Once i recreated the user i changed home location and used gui prompt to delete old home directory and take ownership of external directory. No longer getting the 530 error!!! Kudos to you phip for the help and the idea that helped me fix it! Loving linux and stretching the brain getting it all figured out!